# Watching for model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in my directive's link function:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        $(elem).datagrid({
            columns: [[
                { field: 'ck', checkbox: 'true' },
                { field: 'ProjectID', title: 'Project ID', width: '30%' },
                { field: 'Name', title: 'Name' }
            ]]                
        });
        ngModel.$render = function (value) {
            $(elem).datagrid('loadData', ngModel.$viewValue);
        };
        scope.$watch('projectList', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            $(elem).datagrid('loadData', ngModel.$viewValue);
        });

    }
```

When Array $scope.projectList is initially assigned with data both listeners are fired. Somewhere in my controller (just for testing) I am adding another element to $scope.projectList:

```
$scope.test = function () {
    var project = $scope.projectList[0];
    $scope.projectList.push(project);
}
```

At this point none of listeners are fired.Can someone please explain why that is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the normal $watch function just looks at reference equality, so if you did something like this:

```
var project = $scope.projectList[0];
$scope.newProjectList = [];
$scope.newProjectList.push(project);
$scope.projectList = $scope.newProjectList;
```

Then it would trigger your watch because the object reference of $scope.projectList changed.

If you wanted your example:

```
var project = $scope.projectList[0];
$scope.projectList.push(project);
```

to trigger the watch, then you would either have to do

```
scope.$watch('projectList', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $(elem).datagrid('loadData', ngModel.$viewValue);
}, true);
```

(Passing true as the last argument to $watch causes $watch to do a deep equality comparison, which can be slow with big objects or large lists)

OR

```
scope.$watchCollection('projectList', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $(elem).datagrid('loadData', ngModel.$viewValue);
});
```

(This is similar to the regular $watch in terms of reference equality, but it was made especially for lists. So, on top of the main reference check, it also does a reference check of each of the items in the collection or array, so it would trigger from things like .push and .pop)

They all have their advantages, depending on what kind of checks you're looking for. Also, remember that the $watch returns a deregister function that you can use to clear it out, which you would usually do inside scope.$on('$destroy'. If you don't, they just stay around for a while and can be a drain if you have a lot.

Here's a good
[article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm) on all the differences between the 3 flavors of watch

Answer (score 2):

`$watch` is only checking if the *reference* to the `projectList` array has changed, it does not perform a deep watch on the collection. When you assign the array to the scope variable, you change this reference, but subsequently modifying this array leaves the reference intact. In your case, using the `$watchCollection()` method seems more suitable.

it's worth noting, though, that `$watchCollection` only checks if the collection element references have changed, e.g. by adding/removing/replacing an item. It does not check if those elements themselves have been modified.

If you want to have a deep watch on your collection, pass a `true` as the third parameter to `$watch()`.

```
scope.$watch('projectList', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $(elem).datagrid('loadData', ngModel.$viewValue);
}, true);  // <--- note the objectEquality flag set to true
```

Note, however, that this might have performance implications if the items in the collection are complex and require more time to compare them.

You can also check [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for $scope for more information (scroll down a bit for `$watch()` and `$watchCollection()` method descriptions).

Comment: Seems like changing to $watchCollection did it. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I also updated an answer with some additional explanation on what happens behind the scenes and when even `$watchCollection()` might not be enough (depending what changes need to be detected).

Comment: Just one more thing. Why  ngModel.$render is not firing either when I am modifying the collection?